# Domain going to index of / page instead of home page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, linode

Sorry if this is stupid I am new to hosting. I have set up a server with linode and everything is working except when I go to my domain it brings me to a index of page:

Index of /

Name   Last modified Size    Description
[DIR]   folder1/    2016-04-07 15:08    -
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at xx.xx.xx.xx Port 80

I want to have it go to the theme that is in folder 1. I am assuming I need to setup my .htaccess file but when I do it gives me a 500 error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you wnat to change the web root? or redirect?

Comment: for example my domain is example.com I want it to redirect to example.com/folder1

Comment: We're not magicians! It's hard to tell what you're asking. Edit your question to include an illustration of what's wrong, among other useful details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create htaccess and add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /folder1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what the issue was but after a reinstall of mod_rewrite your code worked perfectly.